# SpriteKit Xcode level editor no touch events on custom button class (3d touch)

Tags: xcode, button, sprite-kit

I am having trouble getting custom SKSpriteNode buttons to work with the xCode level editor on devices with 3d Touch.

I have a button subclass which is mostly based on the DemoBots sample from apple.

The basic code would be this

```
enum ButtonIdentifier: String {
    case playButton
    case pauseButton
}

/// Button responder delegate 
protocol ButtonDelegate: class {
    func pressed(button button: ButtonNode)
}

class ButtonNode: SKSpriteNode {

    public weak var delegate: ButtonDelegate? {
         return scene as? ButtonDelegate
    }

     var isHighlighted = false {
         didSet {
            // running skactions to colorise buttons and animate
         }
     }

    var identifier: ButtonIdentifier!


     /// Code init (when button is created in code)
     /// e.g let playButton = ButtonNode(imageNamed: "ButtonImage", identifier: playButton)

     init(imageNamed: String, identifier: ButtonIdentifier) {
           self.identifier = identifier
           let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)
           super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())

           name = identifier.rawValue
           setup()
     }

     /// Level editor init (when button is created in level editor)
     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)

          // Ensure that the node has a supported button identifier as its name.
          guard let nodeName = name, identifier = ButtonIdentifier(rawValue: nodeName) else {
              fatalError("Unsupported button name found.")
          }

          self.identifier = identifier
          setup()
      }

      private func setup() {

         // zPosition
         zPosition = 200

         // Enable user interaction on the button node to detect tap and click events.
          userInteractionEnabled = true
       }


      #if os(iOS)
      override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
          super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

          isHighlighted = true
     }

      override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
         super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)

         guard let scene = scene else { return }

         for touch in touches {
             let location = touch.locationInNode(scene)
             let node = scene.nodeAtPoint(location)

             if node === self || node.inParentHierarchy(self) {
                 runPressedAction()
             } else {
                 isHighlighted = false
             }
         }
     }

     override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
         super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
         isHighlighted = false
     }
      #endif

     // MARK: - Pressed Action
     private func runPressedAction() {

       // SKAction that runs a press animation
       delegate?.pressed(button: self)
   }
}
```

If i create the button via the xCode level editor everything is working fine in the simulator or on my iPhone 6, however when using test flight my friend with a 6s Plus gets no touch input on the buttons, he cannot press them.

If I create the button all in code everything works, even on 3d touch devices.

Why is it not working with buttons from the level editor on 3d touch devices? I have been trying to look at apples demo bots sample to see if I missed some setting or something, but I cannot figure it out. (Demo bots buttons do work on my friends iPhone 6s plus)

I know that on 3d touch devices touchesMoved method gets called even though there are no changes in the x/y coordinates. However I don't think this causes my issues because when creating buttons in code everything is working as expected.

Is there some setting in the Xcode level editor I am missing to allow touches on 3d touch devices?

Comment: why would you show irrelevant code,  show the code that actually involves the touch events

Comment: I will update my answer, 1 min. The main reason is that if I create them in code they work completely fine on 3d touch devices. Its just when I use Xcode level editor they don't work.

Comment: Show that part too (How you add it it the scene in code)

Comment: Just added both to the question. Thanks for helping.

Comment: try to put some kind of notification on the scene's didbegintouch,  I have a feeling that the coordinates may be off when using the button from the scene builder

Comment: I tried that already, put an alert in all the touches methods. My friend got nothing at all. It only works when done via code. It so strange because DemoBots does exactly the same and he says it works on his phone. He tried on his iPad, just to make sure it wasn't a test flight thing, and it worked fine. Its just with 3d touch devices.

Comment: Do you think it could be logos they I put over each button and made it a child of the button itself? Again demo bots does the same. It would basically be my next step to try to understand whats going on. Today I added a button in code along the level editor buttons for my friend to test and only the code button worked.

Comment: that is weird,  I wish I had a 3d touch capable device to test this out

Comment: yes, that may be a problem,  I believe there is a bug with z order touching

Comment: Same here, need a 3d touch device. I looked at demo bots like 20 times and cannot find a difference. He even has another bug where the score label does not update on his phone whereas on every other device it works as expected. Thats for another question tho. Thanks again I will check the zPosition order now and see what demo bots does and I report back when my friend does another test. Just strange that it works fine in the simulator or on a real iPhone 6. Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: Hey, so I tried without any logos and it is still not working on 3d touch devices. Im running out of ideas lol

Comment: I posted an updated incase you interested. Turns out it was an iOS 9 bug. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of frustration it turned out it was a iOS 9 bug. My friend was on iOS 9.2.x and after he updated to the latest iOS 9.3.x version everything is working, no code changes where required at all.